# debug delphi application / DLL called inside a thread

Tags: delphi

problem description :

```
.....   ( this code is executed inside a thread.execute 
...

if fileexists(myFile) then 
    begin
    //  call functions inside a  DLL 
    ...
    dll_process_data ( .....) ;
    ....
    end;


.....   (clean up ) 

write_clean_data_fct(...)

.....  //

...    //  AV happens here inside kernel.dll , no further information
```

If the file is not found the complete routine / multithreaded algos is executed without any problem; If i add the additional files some  data is processed inside a dll, this is also done without trouble.
Somewhere after the write_clean_data_fct the AV happens now. INside the dll I open a file read data and do data processing with these data.

Q: what might be the reasin and how to debugg this issue ??
Can#t post more lines of code because the complete code sequence is  ~ 15.000 LOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug the DLL like this:

1. Open the DLL project in your IDE.
2. Make sure the host is going to load the DLL from the same path as your DLL project's output directory.
3. Set a break point on the function you wish to debug.
4. From the menu select *Run | Host application* and specify the host executable.
5. Run.

You should now be able to debug code in the DLL. In modern versions of Delphi, you should also be able to step into the DLL code when debugging the host executable. This requires you to have built the DLL with debug information, and for the host executable to load the DLL from the DLL project's output path.

Your actual problem sounds a little tricky. The access violation perhaps occurs long after the erroneous code executes. To debug that, you might first identify the code that raises the exception. Which part of that code has a pointer that could be invalid? Then track back to anything in the DLL that could have modified that pointer.

If static analysis does not help then you can add debugging tools. You'll want:

1. Range checking enabled to detect obvious buffer overruns.
2. Full FastMM debug to detect heap corruptions, access after free etc.
3. madExcept to give detailed diagnostics and stack traces for the actual exception.

You'll want these tools in all modules.

Comment: I've added some text on how to debug such scenarios.